# Instances in instance-group rebooting when given sudo poweroff

Tags: google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I have a strange problem whereby instances in an instance-group reboot themselves when I give them a `sudo poweroff` command (I'm doing this in a startup-script is that makes any difference...)

I've also tried the more elaborate `gcloud compute instances delete -q --zone europe-west1-c $HOSTNAME` to no avail.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance groups spawn and restart instances on demand as required by its management policy. If necessary, when an instance goes down, the policy will wake it again; when deleted, another one will be created in its place.

Removing an instance from an instance group requires modifying the instance group as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#removing_instances). Resizing the instance group size depends on the management policy:

- For replica pool managed instance groups check [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/replica-pools/resize)
- For autoscaler managed instances groups check [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/autoscaler/update)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, these links led me to the right way to do this. Half my problem was that I'm using the python API library to create the instance-group, and the `gcloud preview instance-groups` / `gcloud preview replica-pools` command doesn't always play well with instances created that way...

Comment: I verified this using the Developers Console to create the resources and got the same behavior. So, I don't think this is related to using the API, but to the way the management policy  manages the instances in the group.

Comment: You're right, I was just getting lucky. On further investigation, disabling auto-restart in the instance template used by the instance-group seems to have done the trick. Thanks for your help!